# Docker | How to build and deploy war file in jboss container hosted in Docker

Tags: maven, docker, jboss, docker-compose

I have a jboss image hosted in Docker, along with several others. I am able to run the jboss image and use it as container to deploy webapps.
Currently using IntelliJ to configure a Docker configuration and deploy war files directly from IntelliJ and pointing to the docker configuration within IntelliJ.

I am looking for ways by which I can deploy this war file directly in my jboss image at Docker.
Basically looking at ways to deploy war file without any IntelliJ intervention, with the use of docker-compose to build jboss image along with added war targets successfully deployed.
What sort of changes need to be done in jboss.yml file and Dockerfile for jboss image?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the .war file to be integral part of your image, then you just need to add it as a file resource to your jboss deployment dir during your image assembly via dockerfile. Say your docker file goes like this:

```
FROM jboss/wildfly
COPY myapp.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
```

Of course you need to adjust the paths to match your setup and distribution, you can for example use [maven docker plugin](https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin).

Other option is just to build your server without any deployments and use jboss cli or web admin interface to deploy it. Again you can automate it via maven or RUN command in dockerfile.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the maven docker plugin.
I tried to add the war in deployments folder of jboss image @ docker through COPY/ADD
Another concern for me is, specifying the server settings for jboss server(which I added in the erstwhile Jboss configuration @ IntelliJ IDE). I probably will have to play with jboss image hosted at docker machine to make those changes. Can you confirm on this approach?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by ,,jboss configuration @intellij", but in general, all jboss config is stored in a single file - standalone.xml or domain.xml(if you run cluster). Therefore you can prepare the standalone.xml and copy it to your image via docker `ADD standalone.xml /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/` or you can execute jboss cli commands with your config changes. You can find good articles on jboss@docker online, for [example from Marek Goldmann](https://github.com/goldmann/wildfly-docker-configuration)